# Efficient way of training a chabot AI

Tags: ai, text, bot, character-development

I am currently working on a chatbot game using Python 2.7.10.
I use the [Chatterbot library](http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/training.html). 
This library seems to do all I need but the training data (or corpora) are very very limited.

I haven't quite decided what the game is going to be like.  I was thinking of doing something where the bot contacts you on behalf of a assassinated police inspector and asks you to help it solve the case.

But I am still at the stage where I am experimenting what can and can't be done using a chatbot.

An alternative to this game would be a simple "guess who" kind of game.

I had a look online expecting to find a lot of every day conversation chat logs especially made for training chat bots. But I could only find a few logs of quiet random conversion (mostly on programming). I thought of using plays and film scripts but that requires a lot of editing. What recommendations would you have.  I basically need strings lists in which each string is a response to the previous one. I can also train pairs of question answer.

Comment: I think you would first need to tell us what role that chatbot is supposed to play in the game you are developing.

Comment: I've added a description of what I would want to achieve.  But at this stage I'm still looking for a bot which can hold a basic conversation.